# How to include maven executable to uber jar to run maven commands in AWS Lambda

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am currently AWS Lambda using Java Run time.I have a use case to run maven junit tests in AWS Lambda.Currently Lambda Handler can only invoke the code in src/main.

Is there a way to invoke my src/test tests as part of handler call in AWS Lambda.

Comment: I'm curious as to why your use-cases requires test code to be executed. Why not move the code you need out of test and into src/main/java?

Comment: I want to run cucumber tests in src/test